# Oracle Regex - Splitting a string by more than 1 delimiter

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm looking to currently split a string in Oracle by more than 1 character.

Currently I'm splitting a set of numbers by a space like so:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('123 456', '(^| )([^ ]*)') from dual
SELECT regexp_substr('123 456', '(^| )([^ ]*)', 1, 2, null, 2) from dual
```

etc. which returns back 123 and then 456.

However I'm looking to have a scenario where I could input "123 456-789" and be able to split the numbers into "123" "456" "789".

I've tried

```
(^| )([^ ]*)|^[^-]*[^ -]
```

as my new regex expression but no joy.

Comment: Following your appoach, it should be `'(^|[ -])([^ -]*)'` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z6QmoJ/1)), or why not just ``'\d+'``?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect! Thank you so much - If you'd like to submit an answer - I'll happily mark it as accepted. Always find regex hard to work with lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|[ -])([^ -]*)', 1, 1, null, 2) AS first,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|[ -])([^ -]*)', 1, 2, null, 2) AS second,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|[ -])([^ -]*)', 1, 3, null, 2) AS third
FROM   table_name
```

Or, more simply, don't look for delimiters, just look for numbers:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 1) AS first,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 2) AS second,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 3) AS third
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '123 456'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123-456 789' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| VALUE | FIRST | SECOND | THIRD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 456 | 123 | 456 | *null* |
| 123-456 789 | 123 | 456 | 789 |

---

However, if you only ever have single character delimiters, you can use simple string functions (which is more to type but may be more efficient):

```
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN sep1 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, 1, sep1 - 1)
       ELSE value
       END AS first,
       CASE
       WHEN sep2 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, sep1 + 1, sep2 - sep1 - 1)
       WHEN sep1 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, sep1 + 1)
       END AS second,
       CASE
       WHEN sep2 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, sep2 + 1)
       END AS third
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         normalised_value,
         INSTR(normalised_value, ' ', 1, 1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(normalised_value, ' ', 1, 2) AS sep2
  FROM   (
    SELECT value,
           TRANSLATE(value, ' -', '  ') AS normalised_value
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
```

Which has the same output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6HGO-zgC)

Comment: he wants to find the third number, improving the regex is good v´but didn't answer the question

Comment: The regex rule works though, as adding a check for the third "block" returns back 789 when I input "123 456-789"

Comment: @nbk Updated to include a third match (changing `2` to `3`).